# Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder not generating samples

Tags: jmeter, sample

I am new to JMeter and have been following the steps outlined in usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf.
I am using the Recording Controller.
I have tried to connect to http://jmeter.apache.org/ per the steps outlined but no samples are generated.

I stopped the Proxy and confirmed that i could no longer load pages, so I am confident that I am connecting via the proxy.

Why are no samples being generated?
I'm not seeing any errors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check following fields in Recorder:

- URL Patterns to Include
- URL Patterns to Exclude
- Content-Type Filter : Include, Exclude

If one of them contains wrong pattern or info, sampler will not be generated as JMeter will consider you exclude it.

Also check you don't have errors in jmeter.log

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that your browser is configured to use a proxy? The majority of browsers have `no proxy for localhost/127.0.0.1` or something like that. It's likely that your accessing your application not through JMeter proxy but directly.

By the way, do you know that there is an [extension for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) which can record JMeter scripts right from browser without having to worry about proxies, certificates, etc?

Comment: Thanks - the proxy was configured correctly. I'm checking out blazemeter, too.